# What is the proper command to encode a video for Google TV (Logitech revue) for streaming using mencoder

Tags: streaming, android-mediaplayer, google-tv, mencoder, mkv

I am pretty new to Streaming but I have a nodeJS app up and streaming a video that I can see in my browser. It doesn't, however, work on the Google TV browser so I created a Simple Android App using the VideoView and setting the URL to the GET request location of the file. I can't seem to get it to work. I believe it is not properly encoded, because I can get it to work with this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575048/having-error-message-sorry-this-video-cant-play-to-play-online-video-in-video).

Can someone please give me the proper arguments to encode an HD MKV to a Google TV readable format? Preferably using mencoder or avconv, because I am on a linux PC.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats) is the supported video format from Google.

Comment: please provide the exact url to your streaming media file.

Comment: Well I am hosting it locally currently. Is there not a way to just convert every type of video (90% of codecs) fairly easy?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wealth of info here (http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Mencoder) about using Mencoder. Its a little hard to diagnose your issue without more info (such as the media file to look at). I would suggest you try transcoding to an mp4 h264 format and see if that works for you. Then you can try applying different combinations of container/formats to see what works best for size/performance. Since logitech has discontinued the revue it may hard to get support.

One thing you may want to consider is moving to some of the newer generation hardware such as Visio's CoStar that just started to go on sale for pre-order (http://www.vizio.com/costar/overview/?utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=Co-Star&utm_content=Google) for $99

Mkv's can be tricky - do consider using a different format if you continue to have issues.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the wealth of info, I think the issue is with the size of the video (maybe that is where I am at now). I tried looking at the documentation but for some reason I still get issues, that is why I was looking for an exact. With the CoStar, will that control my receiver over optical? I was also wondering about that with the AppleTV.